# Resize an image in a PictureBox to as large as it can go, while maintaining aspect ratio?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, picturebox

I'm trying to make it so that an image in a PictureBox control will adjust its size automatically depending on the size of the window, but maintain the aspect ratio. So far just setting `SizeMode` to `StretchImage` causes the image to stretch to fit the entire PictureBox control. This ignores the aspect ratio, which isn't what I want.

Is it possible to maintain the aspect ratio, but still stretch the image to the largest it can go dynamically as the form's size changes? Is it possible to do this *and* have it still be centered? I imagine I could recreate the image in memory each time the window is resized, but this seems like a bad idea.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I believe that this is the effect of [`PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.pictureboxsizemode.aspx). The documentation says that:

> The size of the image is increased or decreased maintaining the size ratio.

You set this on the [`PictureBox.SizeMode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.picturebox.sizemode.aspx) property. The "Remarks" section of the documentation for that function also says:

> Using the Zoom value causes the image to be stretched or shrunk to fit the PictureBox; however, the aspect ratio in the original is maintained.

You can, of course, set the `PictureBox.SizeMode` property either in the designer's Properties Window or in code (e.g., in your form's constructor):

```
myPictureBox.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom;
```

If this doesn't do exactly what you want, you could always implement the resizing logic yourself.  Your concern is that recreating the image in memory each time that the control is resized "seems like a bad idea", but I'm not sure why it seems that way to you. The only problem would be if you weren't careful to destroy unused graphics objects, like the old `Bitmap`. Not only do these objects contain unmanaged resources that need to be freed, you'll start exerting extreme amounts of pressure on memory if you just let them leak.

Alternatively, to avoid creating temporary bitmaps, you can do what the PictureBox control probably does internally and use the [`Graphics.DrawImage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.drawimage.aspx) method to handle the stretching. If you pass it a rectangle, it will automatically scale the image to fit inside of the rectangle.

Comment: Thanks, somehow I completely missed the 'Zoom' setting. This does exactly what I want, although it's nice to know the internals that you explained, especially Graphics.DrawImage - I may have a use for that in the future...

Answer (score 2):

Change the 'SizeMode' to `Zoom`. 
As the name suggests, "StretchImage" will stretch it to fit the image file. Easy process of elimination would have given you the same result.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [`PictureBoxSizeMode` documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.pictureboxsizemode.aspx) you can specify `PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom` to get the image to keep its aspect ratio. It will zoom as big as possible without any part of the image overflowing the picture box.

And you can play with the [`Dock` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.dock.aspx) (setting [`DockStyle.Fill`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.dockstyle.aspx)) to get the picture box to resize to the size of its container.

Answer (score -4):

You can add it to a Web Browser control. Using Ctrl and mouse button you can zoom in as much as you like.